# ID in image tag fails

Tags: php, html, key-value

Trying to set an `id = $x` - but it fails!

```
<img src='images/Rename.png' id='".$x."' title='Create new item' border=0 width='20px' height='20px' class='item_create_button'>
```

`$x` is in a `for()` so it starts with 1

looking at it with Firebug - it shows that the `id = 0` (but the lines before it has id=1

Now, trying to - just for the test of it - set it to an input field:

```
<input type=button id='".$x."' title='Create new item' border=0 width='20px' height='20px' class='item_create_button'>
```

it shows in Firebug that id=1 !?

Why can't I set the id in an img tag to anything!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax,

```
for ($x=0; $x<100; $x++) {
   echo "<input type=button id='".$x."' title='Create new item' border=0 width='20px' height='20px' class='item_create_button'>";
}
```

Comment: That's a decent answer, except that ID's 'probably' should not start with a number. Starting it with a '-' or a '_' is 'probably' ok. Starting with a letter is safest.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But I would like the <img id=1> and not <img id=0>

Comment: @osomanden CSS ids can't start with a number. http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/ - but they can contain numbers, so prefix it with a letter.

Comment: @JAL Lets just - for arguments sake ;-) - say that I am aware of that and is trying to - regardless of that - set an id=somevalue. If I do it on an input tag - id is set correctly (even if I prefix it with eg. A.
So I just tried it with prefix: code: <img id='A".$x."' .....> and it is still showing - <img id=A0 .....>

Comment: IF you consider my answer correct, can you mark it as correct?